# Post php somente com todos os campos preenchidos

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Meu formulário está sendo sempre enviado, mesmo se nao tem nada no input, alguem pode me dar uma luz?

HTML:

```
<form id="ajax" method="post">
     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control required" placeholder="Nome">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control required" placeholder="E-mail">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control required" placeholder="Telefone (com DDD)">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="autocomplete"  name="city" class="form-control required" placeholder="Cidade"/>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="zip_code" placeholder="Compra, construção, quitar financiamento?">
     </div>
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default quote_btn" value="Solicitar proposta">
</form>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ajax').submit(function(){
        var dados = $( this ).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "lead.php",
            data: dados,
            success: function( data )
            {
                alert('Enviado com sucesso');
            }
        });

        return false;            
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o plugin **[jQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)** que valida todo o formulário antes de requisitar o Ajax. Você pode inclusive criar regras e mensagens para cada campo. Muito simples e fácil de usar. Carregue o script na página:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

E o script com o validador e o Ajax juntos:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#ajax').validate({  
    
      //regras e mensagens para os campos
      rules: {  
          name: { required: true, minlength: 2 },  
          email: { required: true, email: true },  
          phone: { required: true },
          city: { required: true },
          zip_code: { required: true }
      },  
      messages: {  
          name: { required: 'Informe o nome', minlength: 'Mínimo 2 letras' },  
          email: { required: 'Informe o seu email', email: 'Informe um email válido' },  
          phone: { required: 'Informe o telefone' },
          city: { required: 'Informe a cidade' },
          zip_code: { required: 'Informe o CEP' }
   
      },
      
      submitHandler: function(form){

           var dados = $(form).serialize();
           alert("Formulário OK!"); // apenas exemplo, pode apagar esta linha
    
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "conecta.php",
               data: dados,
               success: function( data )
               {
                   alert('Enviado com sucesso');
               }
           });
   
           return false;            
      }
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="ajax" method="post">
     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control required" placeholder="Nome">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control required" placeholder="E-mail">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control required" placeholder="Telefone (com DDD)">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="autocomplete"  name="city" class="form-control required" placeholder="Cidade"/>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="zip_code" placeholder="Compra, construção, quitar financiamento?">
     </div>
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default quote_btn" value="Solicitar proposta">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Usando HTML5

A solução mais **simples** para esse problema, sem utilizar JS é utilizar somente o atributo **required** do próprio HTML5 nos campos de input. Assim, o próprio browser do usuário **não** deixará o formulário ser enviado se ele não estiver completo.

Logo, o código fica assim:

```
<form id="ajax" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control required" placeholder="Nome" required >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control required" placeholder="E-mail" required >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control required" placeholder="Telefone (com DDD)" required >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="autocomplete" name="city" class="form-control required" placeholder="Cidade" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="zip_code" placeholder="Compra, construção, quitar financiamento?" required >
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default quote_btn" value="Solicitar proposta">
</form>
```

## Usando jQuery

Caso ainda queira utilizar o jQuery, é possível utilizar um loop nos elementos do formulário e verificar se os mesmo são válidos, desse modo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ajax').submit(function () {
        // Validação dos dados
        var valid = true;
        $.each($("#ajax input"), function (i, value) {
            if (!$(value).val()) {
                valid = false;
            }
        });

        if (!valid) {
            alert("Forumlário inválido");
            return false;
        }

        // Código do ajax mantido
        var dados = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "lead.php",
            data: dados,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Enviado com sucesso');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```